# Interpret dates put into Excel as mm/dd

Tags: microsoft-excel, date

I would like to input dates in an Excel worksheet using Swedish format dd/mm, however Excel interprets this as mm/dd. That is, writing "7/8" in a cell is converted into Excel date (2019-07-08, YYYY-MM-DD). Other questions asked refer to changing mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy, which can be done through Windows settings, however I can't find a way of changing the mm/dd format.

A string based solution would work as suggested in some answers, however the reason I am asking is because I was manually inputting dates from a list of dates in dd/mm format, and it was annoying to have to twist every date in my head, or (while it would obviously work and be more robust) to have to set up e.g. two columns for month and day.

Comment: Check Excel's locale setting.  If that's set to Sweden's standard, it should accept dates in dd/mm rather than mm/dd.  Once the dates are understood correctly, you can play with the format to display it the way you want.

Comment: @fixer1234 I followed this guide: https://www.webucator.com/how-to/how-set-locale-microsoft-excel.cfm, Locale (in my Swedish Excel it says "Language") is set to Swedish, still doesn't work. Can I change Locale setting someplace else?

Comment: I don't have ready access to Excel, but that link looks like it deals with just the display format.  There should be application settings in the main menu with a locale setting that controls how Excel views everything.

Comment: @fixer1234 I agree :) can't find it...

Comment: Check this out.  The link is for Excel 2016, but it's probably similar: https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/excel-tips/understanding-regional-differences-in-excel/1/

Comment: Just following up.  Did that link get you to the Excel locale setting?

Comment: @fixer1234 Thanks for checking in, that did take me to the locale setting which was set to follow Windows, however this didn't fix the specific issue (no way in Windows of setting how to interpret a XX/YY date).

Answer (score 1):

Windows sets how Excel uses an "XX/YY" input through the "Short Date" setting.

It is not "immediately obvious" that this is so as the closest one seems to be able to set a format would be choosing the "dd/mm/yy" option. But notice that that sets the first two bits entered as day, then month.

Excel will take a two piece entry and add the current year to it. It is always ready to do that and if you make an entry that it recognizes MIGHT be meant to have that done, it will try it, then run it past the operating system settings to see if the result is interpretable via them, and if it is, will accept your entry as a date in the year (which is the current year according to the operating system).

So enter literally "XX/YY" and it will fail outright, or when it makes it "XX/YY/2022" and checks that against the operating system format choices. But use numbers, not letters, and you might win. Naturally, "34/75" won't succeed as there is no result in this scheme that has a month of 34 or 75... But given something like your "7/8" it will use "7/8/2022" and move forward.

Now it has a full year, month, day string to present against the OS choices and finds it might match the short or long date. If they are essentially the same (one's not day-month and the other month-day!) then Excel can make the entry of, say, "7/8" match one and go with whichever way that one has it.

If you picked day-month-year for the short date, it will see "7" as the day and "8" as the month and give that result, converting to its own system at that moment. From that point on, it's a date to it matching what you wanted (and you can change its displayed form all you like without ruining that).

Presumably if the OS short and long date formats are opposing, it chooses the short date format since it knows you entered it in the way a "short date" would be entered. A guess, but I imagine it to be that clever, at least.

So even though the OS doesn't have a format directly matching the desired "dd/mm" it doesn't need one as that is not actually what Excel does. It produces a full three part string to compare to the OS format choices. So you need to pick one of them with the full three parts, not one (non-existent) one with two parts only.

As to locale changing, if you bring up the standard formatting dialog, the one with the first tab for number formatting, and select "Date" in the list of general types of formatting, you will see to the right side a list of some available date formats. Directly under that is the place to click to select a different locale. It is also available in the same way if you choose "Time" or "Special" as your general type of desired formatting. A choice of locale made in any one of them is reflected in the other two, so it doesn't really matter which you select from. As a practical matter though, if you do it from the "Date" general type, you immediately see the available formatting and might select a slightly different one if you do not see what you desire.

Interestingly, some formats that will NOT work when, say, "English (United States)" is selected, and I mean even if you enter their proper formatting string in the "Custom" general type, will now be available. You can select one and go to "Custom" to see its formatting string, copy that, change back to "English (United States)" and try to use it and it fails! How does that make sense? But something to remember as a way to beat the system.

Answer (score 0):

You can always set it like a string, which can be more convenient and less convenient depending on your case

Let's say you have the date you want in one column, "B" for this example(you cna hide it), you would do the following:

```
=Text(day("B2");"00")&"/"&text(month("B2");"00")
```

Excel is very picky about dates in formats different from us dates "mm/dd/yyyy"(and variations), internally it will try to convert any date if it fits the US date template. I have been bited by this more than a couple of times, because we use "dd/mm/yyyy" in my country so with dates like "01/04/2018" excel sometimes goes nuts.

Comment: Yes, this would work. The reason I am asking is because I was manually inputting dates from a list of dates in dd/mm format, and it was annoying to have to twist every date in my head, or (while it would obviously work and be more robust) to have to set up e.g. two columns for month and day.

Comment: @ToivoSäwén Sorry didn't get that from the question. Anyway Excel is not that nice with other date formats. Even if you set up your `locale` vars and specify cell date format, there is chance it will get mixed up